# Accessing fval directly in matlab

Tags: matlab

When optimizing in Matlab, I am often interested in the objective function and less so in the optimal argument. Is there a way to collect the optimal value directly? At present I have to write something like `[x,fval] = fminbnd(myfunction,-1,1)` and then look at `fval` in the next step. If I just say `fminbnd(myfunction,-1,1)`, I will obtain `x` but not `fval`. Can I write something like

```
part(fminbnd(myfunction,-1,1),2)
```

to collect just `fval` and not `x`? I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. But I wonder, why is it such a bad thing to write an extra line of code?

Comment: @Cris Luengo That's too bad. Seems like a poor design, a bit clunky. A propos your question: life's too short I guess?

Comment: Sure. Depends on what you’re used to though. MATLAB is the only language I’m aware of where a function can know how many output arguments are requested and do something different depending on how many outputs it must produce. That is actually very useful sometimes. But it makes it impossible to index into the output, because it’s not one output, it’s multiple. Python returns a single tuple with multiple values, it looks like multiple outputs, but really it’s a single one. If you don’t want `x`, you can do `[~,fval] = fminbnd(…)`.